# Detect click on multiple devices in real time

Tags: php, ajax, web, websocket, real-time

I'm asking for your help because I need to make a webpage that need to communicate in real-time with different user and devices.

**Device1** (on /page1) : simple page waiting for something to happen

**Device2** (on /page2) : simple page with a button

**I want my Device1 to know in real-time when Device2 have clicked the button.**

At first, I started with simple AJAX (in a PHP environment), where my Device1 were requesting the server every 200 milliseconds to know if a click was triggered. My Device2 was sending the information when the user clicked. I'm aware this is a really bad solution, because of the number of requests I send to the server in a very short interval, and I would like to find something less greedy...

I heard about WebSockets, unfortunatly, it seems that WebSockets only works with Nodejs, and needs to be on a dedicated server.

Do you guys know if there are some alternatives to WebSockets that could fit my needs and can be hosted in a shared hosting ? I only need to detect a "click" from a device to another, nothing else.

Thank you very much for your help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Websocket now exist also in php. You can check this for example: http://socketo.me/

But it doesn't use webserver like apache or nginx, so the solution depends on the type of hosting you have.

Comment: My hosting solution (Professional Hosting on OVH, not dedicated), allows me to use Composer, so I guess I could install Ratchet, but I don't know if it would allow me to use WebSocket protocol...

Comment: The problem would be to open the custom needed ports, but it seems to be compatible with your hosting solution

Comment: Thanks for helping, my hosting solution unfortunatly wouldn't allow me to open ports. I decided to change my plan to a VPS, I think I could use either NodeJS or PHP in order to use WebSockets. Thanks !